# How to publish an artifact of Azure Pipelines into the main branch of the repository?

Tags: bash, git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a file into my repository with the version of the current build, that gets updated automatically whenever there's a push to the main. I've tried using

```
- task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            sudo echo "$(major).$(minor).$(patch)" > version.txt
            cat version.txt
```

But, even if the cat command shows the correct content, the file is not getting created on the repo.

One colleage of mine suggested me using an artifact, and I've developed the following code:

```
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        sudo echo "$(major).$(minor).$(patch)" > version.txt
        cat version.txt
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    inputs:
      publishLocation: filepath
      targetPath: version.txt        # path to the folder or file to publish
      artifactName: version      # name of the artifact to create
```

The artifact is correctly made and I can download it and see the correct version number. Is there a way to push this artifact directly into the root of the main branch of my Azure repo? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sudo echo` ??? !!!

Comment: @phd I've tried both echo and sudo echo in order to know why I wasn't able to create a file on the repository

Comment: You cannot use `sudo echo > file` to overcome permission problems redirecting to file because 1st shell does the redirect before running `sudo`; if the redirect fails shell doesn't even start `sudo`. My advice is to remove `sudo` here.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to push this artifact directly into the root of the
> main branch of my Azure repo?

Jukkak is right. To push the artifact (`version.txt` in your scenario) directly into the root of the main branch of Azure repo, you need to run git commands to add the `version.txt` file and then commit it to push into the repo. See [Run Git commands in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

> I'm trying to create a file into my repository with the version of the
> current build, that gets updated automatically whenever there's a push
> to the main. I've tried using

However, according to your above description, the CI trigger is enabled in your pipeline on main branch, so that a new pipeline will be triggered whenever there's a push to the main. That means it will trigger a new pipeline when the `version.txt` is pushed into the main branch of the Azure repo. To avoid this, we can include `[skip ci]` in the message of any of the commits that are part of a push, and Azure Pipelines will skip running CI for this push. See [Skipping CI for individual pushes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#skipping-ci-for-individual-pushes)

The final YAML for your reference:

```
trigger:
- main

variables:
 system.debug : true
 major: '1'
 minor: '0'
 patch: $[counter(variables['minor'], 1)]

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - checkout: self
    persistCredentials: true
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        sudo echo "$(major).$(minor).$(patch)" > version.txt
        cat version.txt
        git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
        git config --global user.name "Your name"
        git status
        git checkout -b main
        git add --all
        git status
        git commit -m "Push version.txt to repo and [skip ci]"
        git push origin main
        git status
      workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do git add and commit after creating the file (I presume you are using Git since you are talking about repository):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

The artifact you are talking about is really just a concept, and not a tangible thing you can or should be committing anywhere. In reality when you are publishing a pipeline artifact you are really just storing a file, folder structure or a compressed package somewhere where it can be downloaded by another stage or pipeline. In your example, it's just a file, so you'll commit that file. You would, of course, need to checkout the main-branch if the pipeline checks out some other branch at the start of the run.